# Java: How many times is arr.length called in a for-loop?

Tags: java

If `arr` is an array of size 10, in the following code block, how many times is `arr.length` accessed?

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i);
```

Once? Or every time it loops?

Thanks everyone! Here's what I ended up doing:

```
final int len = arr.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i);
```

Comment: `.length` is a field, so it's not called at all, it's being accessed.

Comment: @NUE - That's a bit pedantic...

Comment: I don't think it's pedantic at all. It's a very relevant comment. The OP is attempting a micro-optimization of something that barely needs optimizing at all, especially when it is understood that it isn't a method call.

Comment: I think you should use the first shorter form with `arr.length` in the condition, because it is more readable. Unless you have proven by profiling that the change is worthwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are permitted to change `arr` within the loop, it's usually evaluated every time the loop termination condition is evaluated.

An optimising compiler (or JIT) may recognise that you *don't* change `arr` within the loop, and then only evaluate `arr.length` once.

Comment: +1 for optimising compiler. I think the hotspot editor should pick this up.

Comment: *never* rely on the compiler, nor anything else outside your control, unless you absolutely must

Comment: @George Jempty: I never said anything about relying on the compiler to do anything. I stated what *may* happen, which is true. As always, when evaluating performance differences between different ways of writing code, one must measure each alternative.

Comment: @George Jempty: Though I definitely understand the thrust of your advice, it's useful to consider balancing code readability with optimization. In the case give, I would only keep a separate length variable around if the performance of the loop was an explicit issue.

Comment: @George Jempty: it is reasonable to rely on the Java compilers to do a good job of optimizing.  Indeed, aggressive hand-optimizing risks making things worse ... in a future release of Java with a more sophisticated compiler.  (Probably not in this case though.)

Comment: @Stephen C: if a compiler could screw up the way I write my for loops, time to find a different compiler ... or language

Comment: It won't "screw it up".  It just will generate suboptimal code.  But you will find this whenever you change compile versions with ANY language with an optimizing compiler.  The point is that ANY optimizing compiler's ability to optimize can be defeated by you writing complicated code ... for whatever reason.  At least with Java, it is less likely that the compiler will "break" your code ... unlike C or C++ for example.  (I say "break" in quotes because the real bugs are usually in your code ... not the optimizer.)

Comment: The situations where a compiler could "break" Java code are (AFAIK) all due to latent concurrency / thread safety bugs in the application code.

Comment: If `arr` is declared final it can not be changed inside the loop, and the compiler can more easily optimize accesses to its length.

Answer (score 7):

Eleven times....

10 times, the statement `i < arr.length` evaluates to `true`.
1 time it evalutes to `false` and the loop ends.

Comment: You most directly answered my question, but Mr. Hewgill gave the _reasoning_ behind it, so I selected his answer.

Comment: Is this homework (needing to know how many times something executes because of a poorly implemented algorithm), or would actually like to know the *one* *best* way to do this?  If the latter, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Without compiler optimizations, 11 times (one per iteration + one after the last iteration). But the compiler will optimize the thing so there's going to be only one access. But what I said assumes your for loop has a body:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
   ...
}
```

In your case the loop has no body:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i);
```

so it's a no-op and the compiler is going to remove it. So in that specific case you'll access the field zero times.

But don't rely on compiler optimizations because you don't really know what it does.

Comment: The compiler still has to check that arr isn't null ;)

Comment: @tc. That's right. Moral: Don't rely on compiler optimizations

Answer (score 3):

**zero** is a possible answer in a decent modern vm.

in your specific loop, since it doesn't do anything, *most likely* vm will completely bypass it.

in the following example

```
size = ...
arr = new byte[size];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    non-trivial-statements;
```

vm could deduce that arr.length==size, which is already in a register, therefore `size` is used directly.

more interestingly, it *knows* that `i<arr.length` already , therefore `arr[i]` doesn't need runtime bound check,  making array access as cheap as C array.

However, Java the language doesn't dictate these things. a vm can access it zero times, or a million times, it's all correct as long as the observable effects are the same.

the point is, you shouldn't worry about it. programs written in the common fashion are most likely subject to heavy optimization. following the crowd pays off in this case.

Comment: I prefer "write what you mean and let the compiler make it fast"

Answer (score 1):

Every time it loops by definition. 
It might be optimized to 1 if you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

for `(int i=0, n=arr.length; i<n; i++);` is a simple idiom that neither

- a) relies on the compiler nor
- b) requires a non-loop scoped variable
  to hold the length, and
- c) evaluates arr.length just once

Comment: "the one best way to do this"? IMHO, everyone who doesn't want to leave such optimizations to compiler, should try assembler. There he'll be able to optimize each tiny detail.

Comment: Is the assumption here that it's only beneficial to use this approach when the evaluation of arr.length is know to be highly expensive and/or arr.length happens to be a significantly large number (causing the evaluation to take place numerous times) AND you don't trust the compiler to recognize that arr.length will never change?

Comment: @Nikita: look at your own statement in the mirror: implicit in it is some sort of knowledge of what's going on inside the compiler when you cannot possibly know for sure, unless you are intimately familiar with 'each tiny detail'.  The idiom I suggest is both simple and long established.  I could be mistaken but I think it even dates to K&R.  Want to argue with them, be my guest.

Comment: @George I'm not saying I'm sure it will be optimized. I'm saying that I don't care. There're always ways to optimize code a bit more and the one you suggest doesn't even bring any noticeable difference (unlike some advanced optimizations, like famous quick sort example from Dragon Book). But ultimately, choosing language like Java, you leave most of them in responsibility of compiler.

Comment: @Nikita: you have got to be kidding about no noticeable difference.  For ten iterations, perhaps, but for ten thousand?  Regarding "choosing language like Java", I am a polyglot, my two other strongest languages being Javascript and PHP, and I use the same idiom in those languages too.

Comment: @George No, I'm not kidding. For each property access there'll be several instructions related to loop itself (increment, comparison, jump + copying data between memory and registers) and dozens (more often hundreds or thousands) of instructions constituting loop body. If that one pathetic property access is still important, then check C++ or assembler. There you'll be able to gain way, way more through optimization. Javascript and PHP were clearly not designed for performance speed, so they're on Java side in this.

Comment: @Nikita, fair enough, since it is a "pathetic property access".  What if it were a method call though?  The idiom I use obviates any necessity to code things in a more optimal way under those circumstances.  It seems like a very good (if not the "one best way" though personally I still believe so) "one size fits all" approach, useful across a number of programming languages, that can become quite natural after doing it a few times, that *guarantees* one property access or method call, rather than one call per loop iteration.

Comment: -1; it still relies on the JIT. A *good* JIT will notice that it can never throw OutOfBoundsException and never do the bounds check; this may be more difficult if it has to infer i < n, n = a.length ⇒ i < a.length. Don't try to outsmart the compiler without any benchmarks.

Comment: And declaring variables in a for initializer wasn't standardized until C99, so I'm pretty sure it didn't exist in K&R.

Comment: I'm not trying to outsmart the compiler.  I'm coding based on the language specification: the non-initialization statements of the for loop get executed once per iteration, so I moved what I could into the initializer.  If a compiler can optimize other ways of doing this, good for it.  If it can screw up my way, again, time to find a new compiler and/or new language, because the compiler in that case would be performing in a way contradictory to the language spec.

Comment: @George Yes, if size check involved any actual algorithm or computation (not array.length or collection.size()), I would have to agree with you. Although I'm still opposed to "let's write whole application in one line!" paradigm, that's probably just a matter of taste.

Comment: George, I didn't say that the length would be fetched repeatedly; I said that the array bounds-check may be executed repeatedly. If you're calling `length()`, then I'd preload it. But for a native array, `a[i] = 1` has to fetch the array length *anyway*. Previous advice was to not check the length because the VM would do it for you, instead catching OutOfBoundsException. By your logic, this is going to run faster because we no longer have to do the integer comparison; in a modern JIT it is likely to run slower.

Comment: From the language spec: "The basic for statement executes some initialization code, then executes an Expression, a Statement, and some update code repeatedly until the value of the Expression is false."

Answer (score 0):

You could also do some experiments like

```
public class Count{

    private static int count; 

    private static int getLength(Object[] arr) {
        count += 1;
        return arr.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        count = 0;
        Object[] arr = new Object[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < getLength(arr); ++i) {
            // do something
        }
        System.out.printf("called %d times%n", count);
    }
}
```

for more details also print the value of `i` and the returned value of `getLength` (or use a debugger).

For fast online testing have a look at [Youjavait](http://youjavait.com/) or [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/).